# Using '%' as a wild card character in a parameter in SQL with Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

So in my program I have:

```
    private static final String GET_USERS_BY_PARAMS = "select * from user t "
        + "where t.id like %?% "
        + "AND t.name LIKE %?% "
        + "AND t.location LIKE %?% " 
        + "AND t.telephone LIKE %?% ";
```

All of the parameters given above are stored as varchar in the database.

However when I run the following:

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_USERS_BY_SEARCH_PARAMS);
            statement.setString(1, userID);
            statement.setString(2, name);
            statement.setString(3, location);
            statement.setString(4, telephone());

            rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

I get a SQL exception stating that there was an invalid character. The application throws the error on the executeQuery, so setting the params isn't an issue. I was wondering if this was down to using the % symbols, whihc I included so that you could search without having to input the exact user ID, name, or etc.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Big thanks to everyone who answered :) Sometimes I hate the fact that I can only accept one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard has to be part of the value passed to the prepared statement. So you need something like this:

```
private static final String GET_USERS_BY_PARAMS = "select * from user t "
    + "where t.id like ? "
    + "AND t.name LIKE ? "
    + "AND t.location LIKE ? " 
    + "AND t.telephone LIKE ? ";

statement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_USERS_BY_SEARCH_PARAMS);
statement.setString(1, "%" + userID + "%");
statement.setString(2, "%" + name + "%");
statement.setString(3, "%" + location + "%");
statement.setString(4, "%" + telephone() + "%");
```

Btw: what datatype is `user.id`?

If that is a numeric value, LIKE won't work correctly. You should probably explictely cast the ID to a character value instead: `where to_char(t.id) like ?`

Comment: The user id is a string e.g. "USER_1234", so it works well, but thanks for the additional information!

Answer (score 2):

use `CONCAT` function,it will works,like this: `LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')` 
or also you can use `LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')`

Answer (score 2):

You can write with concatenation operator

```
LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')
```